# Is there a utility for running a screensaver as a standard window?

Tags: windows, screensaver

Since I have a large widescreen, I'm splitting its area into rectangles (Using winsplit revolution), and thought it might be nice to run a screensaver in one of the smaller unused areas.

Is there a tool or a way to run a screen saver in a window?

Perhaps the preview mode can be used for that somehow?

Answer (score 8):

You can run the screensaver with the /p switch, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/903180/how-to-make-a-screen-saver-preview-in-delphi/903212#903212) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

One option (a huge overkill) might be to run another windows XP in a virtualBox window and make the screensaver run there.

It will probably have problems with 3D screensavers, but it might work.

Answer (score 0):

- Run [MyDefrag](http://www.mydefrag.com/) and resize it to the size you want it
- Turn on [Picasa](http://picasa.google.com/) with some form of Slideshow (this could be any other picture program as well)
- Have Windows Media Player running on full-screen with some splash screen